# Service from sources inside Docker container

Tags: docker

Short question: is it ok (aren't there any contradictions with Docker ideology) to compile and start application from sources inside Docker container?

---

Assume that I have some hypothetical application. Let it be Java web service built with Maven, located somewhere in GitHub. Specifics doesn't matter here.

But before starting this service, I need to set-up several config files with right parameters, known at deployment time. Right now I can build fully-preconfigured application package with a single maven command, passing all the necessary configurations at build command.

Now assume that I need to make it a Docker container and don't have time to refactor it somehow right now. So I have a plan: let my docker image have Maven and Git, ENTRYSCRIPT clones my Git repository, builds and starts the application, passing all the necessary parameters via environment.

Is it suitable plan, or it's just wrong?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "wrong". It's certainly suboptimal, for example the container startup time will be high, and dependent on external resources being available. It seems a lot more sensible to just split your Maven workflow into two steps (build/run).

Comment: By definition of "wrong" I meant "aren't there any contradictions with Docker ideology?". Speaking about external resources - if you meant GitHub, then theoretically I can package the dump of source files into the container and not clone it during startup. Maven phases split-up won't change anything - in fact it is actually not *running* the application, it just builds it with predefined parameters. And again - main purpose of this is to avoid any refactoring and use what we have right now :)

Comment: To add more, this is mostly hipothetical question. I don't intend to use it in production, I just want to understand containerization better. I know it is strange solution, but I haven't seen any direct arguments against it anywhere.